# In this tutorial, what is the "class that extends DroidGap"

Tags: java, android, cordova

I just did the Cordova Hello, World tutorial and now I'm trying to add a splash screen. The [tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen) says

> In the onCreate method of the class that extends DroidGap, add the
>   following two lines.

What is the class that extends DroidGap? How do I find it? What is this tutorial talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [intro tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) instructs you to change the superclass of your new main class to `DroidGap` instead of the default (`Activity`)—so you created and named the "class that extends `DroidGap`"; that's the reason they describe it this way. It's your project's intro `Activity`/main class.

Comment: Ah, gotcha; that'd definitely cause a bit of confusion :). Happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

DroidGap is basically used when we integrate PhoneGap in our Android Application.
Instead of our Activity we have to extend our main class with DroidGap in order to work with Phonegap apps.

Hope this answers your question.